# Are steady-state values in LTI systems differentially influenced by the rate an input is introduced?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a general question about LTI systems I was hoping someone could clarify.
I'm currently learning about steady state behavior in LTI systems, and how you can evaluate them with different inputs. So here's my question-say we have an LTI system, and let's consider 2 different inputs: a step input with a long duration (say maybe 150 time steps), let's call this A. And another input that gradually increases from 0 to 1 (maybe this gradual increase is logarithmic or linear-I wonder if it matters?), in 135 time steps, and then remains at that value for an additional 15 steps-let's call this B. So that means it takes B 135 steps to reach A's value, but it does maintain that value for a little while at least. Are there general features of LTI systems that could help you predict the behavior of the system in response to the abrupt vs. gradual introduction of an input? Will they reach the same steady state values?

My intuition is that they should both give for the same steady state, but that abruptly introducing an input should reach steady state faster. Although I wonder if the gradual case would allow for a more stable system? Does anyone have any thoughts? I'd appreciate it, this has been bothering me for a while now haha

Comment: For an LTI system, steady-state gain is defined by the system, not the input signal. In your example, the time taken for the input to reach a steady value has no influence on steady state gain. Clearly, a slowly increasing input will take longer to achieve steady state than, say, a step input.

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that it doesn't matter that a signal could be increasing linearly or logarithmically (in my example), all that matters is that in case B, the input matches A during the last 15 time steps. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes, when the input remains at a constant value long enough for the output value to also become constant the ratio of output to input is the steady-state gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the inputs to an LTI system stay constant for a time that is greater than the length of the impulse response, the system will reach the steady state for these inputs, regardless of history.

Whenever that is not the case, history matters. How the system reacts to different inputs is completely dependent on the system -- if you look at discrete time systems, `[ 5 -5  0  0  0]` will react differently than `[ 1  1  1  1  1]`.

The first system will reach steady state after just two ticks, but produces fairly violent spikes on every input change:

```
[ 1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11] -> [ 5  0  0  0  0 25  0  0  0  0 25 ...]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15] -> [ 5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5 ...]
```

The second takes five ticks, and smooths out steps of length 5:

```
[ 1  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11] -> [ 1  2  3  4  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 ...]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15] -> [ 1  3  6 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...]
```

You can see that apart from the start the outputs are the same (a ramp increasing by 5 each step).

Comment: Oh, that's really interesting. So basically, what you're saying is that in case B, since the last 15 time steps are equal to A, if 15 is greater than the length of the impulse response, then A and B should promote equal steady state gains? I assume it's the time invariance that makes this happen (about the system)?

Comment: @JohnAlperto, no, the steady state gain would be the output for constant 1 input, and that would be the sum of the coefficients, which in one case is 0, and in the other is 5.

Comment: Note that the output for the ramp is not a steady state, even if it is constant for a differentiator, because that would mean that the input needs to increase forever.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I get what you're saying? Sorry. I was referring to the example in my OP in my previous comment. Aren't we both saying that as long as two inputs have the same constant value for the last 15 steps (and that, according to you, 15 is greater than the length of the impulse response), then they should give the same steady state values? Maybe I'm not understanding your own example well enough.

Comment: Yes, in that case you get the steady state values -- however if you have a continuously rising ramp, then the system will not settle until the end of the ramp plus the length of the impulse response.

Comment: OK, so what you're saying is that if the input is continuously ramping, then it doent matter if the input stays at a constant level afterwards because you have to wait for the output to also stop ramping before it can take on the steady state values? Which implies that the output can be ramping even while the input is constant correct?

Comment: Yes, whenever the impulse response is longer than one coefficient (or to be completely correct: there is a nonzero coefficient with positive time offset -- in theory LTI systems can look into the future and avoid introducing a delay this way, but these are rare in the real world).